# Different class access rules in php

Tags: php, class, methods

I am new to php development class concept, I am calling a method within a class file like

`**ClassName::method_name();**` 
    like this, but it does not work and get an error. When I create an object of that class Like `**$object = new ClassName();**` and call the method through this function Like 
    `**$object->method_name();**` 
    it works fine.

I am unable to understand that trick.

can any one clear my confusion ?
Thanks,

biswajitGhosh

Comment: Did any of the answers below help you?

Comment: Yea ! absolutely, now I can use static keyword of any class's method, I don't know it before.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define your method as static if you want to use `::` notation.

```
class ClassName {
    public static function method_name() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Now you can call `ClassName::method_name();`

Read up: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

Answer (score 2):

The `::` operator is for accessing static methods and properties, the `->` operator is for accessing methods and properties of an instance of a class.

A static method or property is one which belongs to the class itself, and will not change no matter how many instances of that class you create.

An instance method or property applied only the a specific instance of a class, and changes in one instance will not affect another.